# Array_diff() does not produce the right output for two array fetch from the same table in php

Tags: php, mysql

The code i have written is to get the profile id from the table and i want the uncommon one but when i use array_diff or array_diff_assoc the out is []

```
require_once __DIR__  .'/connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$result =  mysql_query("select PROFILE_ID from chat_group_members where GROUP_ID =4");
$reg =  mysql_query("select PROFILE_ID from chat_group_members where GROUP_ID = 5");

$reg1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);//result is profile_id 9
$result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($reg);//result is profile_id 9 and Profile id 11

$result2=array_diff_assoc($result1,$reg1);
echo json_encode ($result2);
//output is blank []
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're going to do this with PHP, don't use `array_diff_assoc` for this, because it checks keys as well as values, so if you have some of the same keys in the second array, but in a different order, it will not match them. Just a plain `array_diff` will work better.

Second, unless there's other code you haven't shown, `$result1` does *not* contain 9 and 11, because `mysql_fetch_assoc`, (or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` if you upgrade to a supported interface) only fetches *one row* from your results.

You need to fetch all of the results before you can do this comparison.

But you don't have to do this in PHP at all. You can do it with one query instead. There are a couple of ways to do it; one way is by using `NOT IN` with a subquery.

```
SELECT PROFILE_ID FROM chat_group_members 
WHERE GROUP_ID = 5
AND PROFILE_ID NOT IN (SELECT PROFILE_ID FROM chat_group_members WHERE GROUP_ID = 4)
```

But you'll still have to fetch all the results. That's often done using a `while` loop. [You can see some examples in the mysqli documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion buddy. I got the desired output actually I forgot that i need to run a loop to get all the array elements.